# Probably a silly,often asked, mistake involving arrays in C

Tags: c

I am very new to C and I am having problems with the following. I initialize the arrays:

```
double Cx[101];
for(int i=0; i<101; i++){
  Cx[i]=-5+i*0.1;
}

double Q[2][101];
double y[101];
```

and I have the following functions outside the main method:

```
double InitHeight(double g, double dx, double x){
  return 3;
}

double InitMom(double g, double dx, double x){
 return 2;
}

double plainTopo(double x){
 return x*10;
}
```

Now, in the main method I do the following:

```
double g=1;
double dx=0.1;
for(int i=0; i<101; i++){
  Q[1][i] = InitHeight(g,dx,Cx[i]);
  Q[2][i] = InitMom(g,dx,Cx[i]);
  y[i] = plainTopo(Cx[i]);
}
```

So, my problem is that the original values of the Cx array get modified. Here is a portion of the original Cx:

```
-5.000000
-4.900000
-4.800000
-4.700000
-4.600000
-4.500000
-4.400000
...
```

and after I run the the code this is what I get:

```
   Cx[]   Q[1][]   Q[2][]     y[]
2.000000 3.000000 2.000000 20.000000
2.000000 3.000000 2.000000 20.000000
2.000000 3.000000 2.000000 20.000000
2.000000 3.000000 2.000000 20.000000
2.000000 3.000000 2.000000 20.000000
2.000000 3.000000 2.000000 20.000000
```

I can't for the life of me see why the Cx array gets modified. I have tried to use pointers instead with the same results, also tried to do
    double x = Cx[i]
in the loop and then pass x to the functions but again Cx gets change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Thanks everybody. That did the trick and I feel a little embarrassed now. But let me ask you guys another question. I have programmed in Java before and usually when there is an index out of bounds error the program would spit an error. Is it not the case for C?

Comment: No, there's no bounds-checking in C. It's the programmer's responsibility to respect the boundaries.

Answer (score 6):

You're indexing into `Q` incorrectly.  Array indices in C start at 0, not 1.  So you should have

```
double g=1;
double dx=0.1;
for(int i=0; i<101; i++){
  Q[0][i] = InitHeight(g,dx,Cx[i]); /* Used to be Q[1][i] */
  Q[1][i] = InitMom(g,dx,Cx[i]); /* Used to be Q[2][i] */
  y[i] = plainTopo(Cx[i]);
}
```

As for why `Cx` gets changed, accessing an out-of-bounds item in an array causes undefined behavior, which means that the C compiler can do anything it feels like.  Your particular compiler generates assignments into `Cx`.  Technically, this is because of the way arrays are laid out on the stack, but the compiler is *not* required to do the same thing that your compiler does, and can instead choose to cause your program to crash (this is the best case, because it helps you find the bug), write over top of other data (this is what you are seeing), or delete all your files (no compiler I know of actually does this).  Really, the compiler has *complete freedom* to cause as much havoc as it feels like whenever undefined behavior occurs, and one such situation is when you access an out-of-bounds array index.

Comment: Man, I feel stupid now. That totally fixed it. Thanks. I am trying to write a program from MATLAB to C and I started from 1 and 2 in there.

Answer (score 5):

This going beyond the bounds of the array `Q`, causing undefined behaviour:

```
Q[1][i] = InitHeight(g,dx,Cx[i]);
Q[2][i] = InitMom(g,dx,Cx[i]);
```

must be `Q[0]` and `Q[1]` as `Q` is defined as:

```
double Q[2][101];
```

The other indexing in your code indicates you are aware that array indexes are zero-based and run from `0` to `N - 1` where `N` is the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
double g=1;
double dx=0.1;
for(int i=0; i<101; i++){
  Q[1][i] = InitHeight(g,dx,Cx[i]);
  Q[2][i] = InitMom(g,dx,Cx[i]);
  y[i] = plainTopo(Cx[i]);
}
```

You do not have a Q[2][i] available, so it's probably overwriting into your Cx array

I think what you meant was

```
Q[0][i] = InitHeight(g,dx,Cx[i]);
Q[1][i] = InitMom(g,dx,Cx[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double Q[2][101];
:
Q[2][i] = InitMom(g,dx,Cx[i]);
```

Your corruption is happening because the legal indexes for Q do *not* include `Q[2][...]`.

You seem to know this since you iterate `i` from 0 to 100 inclusive, for the `Cx[101]` array so it appears to be just a temporary mistake - it's the same rule for *all* dimensions of an array.